# Slap Editor Installation problem, (sudo: npm: command not found)

Tags: command-line, text-editor, nodejs, npm

I'm installing [**Slap Editor**](https://github.com/slap-editor/slap) on Ubuntu 14.04 and when I type `sudo npm install -g slap` its giving me the error `sudo: npm: command not found` .

the node version on my system is `0.10.33` and the npm version is `1.4.28`

I didn't find any solution to this problem, can anyone help me ?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you need sudo? What guide are you following?

Comment: @Seth Actually I was using the method from Slap's Github page. (https://github.com/slap-editor/slap)

Comment: The line before that says "Make sure NodeJS is installed." Is it?

Comment: @muru Yes Node and npm is installed, I mentioned in the question already.

Comment: Yes, but not how you installed it. It might not be in the path, if it was a local installation.

Comment: @muru , I used this method for the installation of node and npm
(https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dwayne/2983873/raw/315605b9fed176c410b95c5699c35603142447c1/install-on-64-bit-ubuntu-14.04.md)

Comment: Yes, that's a local installation (specific to your user). You might want to try this method instead: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: @muru I'm going to try this method than I'll let you know.

Comment: @muru Now when I said "sudo npm install -g slap" (without quotes) , it gave me this error https://gist.github.com/DevotionGeo/a99918c99a764df825be

Comment: @DevotionGeo See line 13: "npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19400/discussion-between-devotiongeo-and-muru).

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution would be to run with full path `sudo /home/geo/nodejs/bin/npm ... blah-blah`

To determine where is npm, run `which npm`.